# How to run JavaFX GUI application on linux startup

Tags: linux, javafx, raspberry-pi

I would like to start my JavaFX GUI application on startup of the system.
The Java application is a fat jar that contains all dependencies. The application was built on linux. I can run it from console without any problem with the following command:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/java -jar /home/my_user/application.jar
```

And that work like a charm but now I would like to run the application on the system startup.

I have already tried a few approaches like:

> Create a file named /etc/xdg/autostart/startup.desktop
> Put the following contents into it

```
[Desktop Entry] Type=Application
Name=JavaApplication
Exec=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/java -jar /home/my_user/application.jar
```

> Restart.

> https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40112/java-gui-app-on-startup

And that resulted in no action at the boot.

Or

```
sudo vim my_startup.service
```

with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sample application autostart
After=graphical.target
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=my_user
WorkingDirectory=/home/my_user
ExecStart=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/java -jar /home/my_user/application.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then:

```
sudo systemctl enable my_startup.service
```

And then:

```
sudo systemctl status -l my_startup.service
```

Results in:

```
× my_startup.service - Sample application autostart
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my_startup.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-12-13 10:02:55 CET; 1h 13min ago
    Process: 684 ExecStart=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/java -jar /home/my_user/application.jar (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 684 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 572ms

dec 13 10:02:55 my_user java[684]:         at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
dec 13 10:02:55 my_user java[684]:         at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:290)
dec 13 10:02:55 my_user java[684]:         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:293)
dec 13 10:02:55 my_user java[684]:         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
dec 13 10:02:55 my_user java[684]:         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
dec 13 10:02:55 my_user java[684]:         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:679)
dec 13 10:02:55 my_user java[684]:         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
dec 13 10:02:55 my_user java[684]:         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
dec 13 10:02:55 my_user systemd[1]: my_startup.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
dec 13 10:02:55 my_user systemd[1]: my_startup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

> https://www.interelectronix.com/pl/raspberry-pi-4-autostart-aplikacji-qt-podczas-uruchamiania-systemu.html

Comment: If it were me, I wouldn't use the approach you are using: "a fat jar that contains all dependencies".  Instead, I would use `jpackage` to create a native distribution for the platform in `rpm` and/or `deb` format and use jpackage's and the rpm/deb installers ability to package additional resources (such as service installation scripts) and configure them on the target system.  That said, I am not a raspberry pi developer, and don't know if it is capable of handling standard install formats like `rpm` or `deb`, if not then ignore my comment :-)

Comment: I had to use the fat jar as some of my dependencies does not support modularity and because of that I cannot use jlink and jpackage.

Comment: Unlike jlink, jpackage does not require software to be modular.  jpackage is more complicated to use than jlink though and has different functions, so it may not fit your requirements for other reasons than the modularity reason you provided.

Comment: The stack trace provided in your question is quite strange. It doesn't say what the actual exception encountered was.